# Enable only check-box click event

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/selecting/row-selection/defaultcs.aspx

I have functionality similar like this but instead I have used grid in which every items are in cell . But in this functionality I want the checkbox should only be selected when it is clicked on checkbox not anywhere except it . 
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states, you would simply set the following to false:

```
ClientSettings.Selecting.AllowRowSelect = false;
```

The sample code provided:

```
  <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">
    <ClientSettings>
      <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
    </ClientSettings>
    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="Fuchsia" BorderColor="Purple" BorderStyle="Dashed"
      BorderWidth="1px" />
  </telerik:RadGrid>
```

The information can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/selecting/selecting-rows/client-side-selecting-with-a-click).  The use that property to trigger an event which selects your checkbox, you would disable that and allow the checkbox to run independantly.

Comment: The whole rows doesn't get selected in my case , but if you click on cell where checkbox is the check-box gets selected , I want only on clicking on check-box should be allowed .